# How can I get the current logged in users unique ID?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

To be able to make it so that an admin only has the option to remove other admins and not themselves, I need to be able to store the ID of the current logged in user. Below is the format for the button that removes the admin privileges from verified admins.

```html
<td *ngIf="user.userRoleID == 1 && user.userID != loggedUserID" style="padding-left: 10px;">
 <button style="width: 100%;" (click)="removeAdmin(user.userID)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Remove
   admin
 </button>
</td>
```

Can someone please explain me how to go about getting the 'loggedUserID' portion of the code? I am using spring boot and angular to create this application.

Comment: Hi stephen/crooks, [why do you create multiple accounts and thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598782/how-do-i-make-it-so-an-admin-in-my-system-cannot-remove-themselves-from-having-a#comment99773703_56598782) ?

Comment: I wanted to create an account using my main email address

Comment: Did you implemented the authentication system ? Or is it someone else ?  A common way to implement authentication client-side is by using a token. If you have no idea what it is, [read a guide](https://medium.com/engineerbabu/angular-authentication-using-jwt-d846c5ce0ac6) and try to implement it.

Comment: According your other question, you seems new to Angular. I suggest you to read the [Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using a service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUser: User; // Here, store the full user or the user id, depending your needs.

  constructor() {
    // [...]
  }

  public login(): void {
    // [...] your call to the API and others...
    this.currentUser = data.user; // Assuming your API returns the user after authentication.
  }

  public getCurrentUser(): User {
    return this.user; // Here you get the current user.
  }

  // [...] other methods
}
```

You can then reference this in any of your component using dependency injection:

```
// [...]
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  // [...]

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedUserID = this.authService.getCurrentUser().id; // set the loggedUserID.
  }
}
```

Note that the below code works because this service is a singleton:

> There are two ways to make a service a singleton in Angular:
>
> - Declare root for the value of the @Injectable() providedIn property
> - Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only imported by the AppModule

Answer (score 0):

In your component you need to define this ' loggedUserID' variable.

I am providing some sample code, as in , how you can wire up everthing, but you can freely use your own component classes / methods / services.

```
export class UserComponent {

      loggedUserID: string;


    constructor(private userService: UserService ) { }

      getUser() {
      this.userService.getUserDetails().subscribe(user => {
          this.loggedUserID = user.id;
        });
}
```

UserService

```
 @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class UserService {
     
    
      public getUserDetails(): Observable<User> {
    
        return this.http.get<User>(url)
                  .pipe(map(data => {
             return data.body;
            }));
        
      }

}
```

User model

```
export class User {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    email: string
}
```

Comment: How do you know he has `userService` and `getUserDetails` ??

Comment: I have given a sample code, as in, how he can wire all the necessary things in order to fetch right information there.